# Collect to set with joining Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Hi I'm trying to have a string represents concatenation of set of names for each teacher, 
thus I need to use both `Collectors.toSet` and  `Collectors.joining(", ")` how can I use them in 1 combine line ?
I can only make each one of them separately  how can i do both of them ?

```
students.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student -> student.getTeacherName(), mapping(student -> student.getName(), toSet())


students.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student -> student.getTeacherName(), mapping(student -> student.getName(), joining(", "))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use `collectingAndThen()`:

```
students.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Student::getTeacherName, 
                 mapping(Student::getName, 
                         collectingAndThen(toSet(), set -> String.join(", ", set)))))
```

Comment: can also do that:
.... collectingAndThen(toSet(), set -> set.stream().collect(joining(", ")) 

in order to have the ability to add more manipulations on the stream such as filter or sort

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already know how to produce the set. We'll call it `teacherSet`.

You want to re-stream after producing the set:

```
// create teacher set...
teacherSet.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

You can also join after you're done producing the set using [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-). Here is an example:

```
String.join(",", Arrays.stream("1,2,3,4,3,2,1".split(",")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or in your case:

```
// create teacher set...
String.join(",", teacherSet);
```